# ASPNETCore 2 POST method not returning a payload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I upgraded a .net core 1 project to .net core 2. Everything is working great however my POST method won't return any data. There is no payload. I must be missing something simple.

The API does receive what I send it, so no issues there. But there is nothing in the response (using Chrome and IE dev tools), no matter what I try.

Here are the response headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Encoding: gzip
>
> Server: Kestrel
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?

For instance this returns no payload:

```
[HttpPost]  
public IActionResult PostOrder([FromBody]OrderDto dto)
{
  return new OkObjectResult(dto);
}
```

Comment: Assuming `dto` is not null, then you should get *something* in the response body. Have you customized the serializers at all? The default would be to serialize the object to JSON. FWIW, you should do `return Ok(dto);` instead. I doubt it will solve your issue, but it's more correct.

Comment: No customization, I'm not sure if the .NET core version change is even relevant. I was able to send the POST in Fiddler and I did get back a response using "return new JsonResult(2)"....However it still returns nothing on the application side.

Comment: That actually lends more credence to `dto` being null. It's really the only thing that would explain an empty response body. Debug, break on the return line and ensure that `dto` does in fact have a value when you submit via Fiddler. Ensure that you're sending the request body with an `application/json` mime-type.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you led me in the right direction. I had another controller that was returning data on the POST. So comparing them, I realized there was a caching policy setting "Location" to none and "NoStore" to true. I removed that and it worked!

Comment: Great. Please post that as an answer to your question and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching policy was setting "Location" to none and "NoStore" to true. Removing this policy solved the issue.